# Why does this for loop that iterates an array throw an exception?

Tags: arrays, exception, swift, for-loop

I keep returning an error from this seemingly obvious for-loop.

```
for var i = 0; i < self.restaurantNames.count; i++ {
    self.names += [Name(name: self.restaurantNames[i], city: self.addressCity[i])]
}
```

#### Error

```
fatal error: Array index out of range
```

Comment: `self.addressCity` has less elements than `self.restaurantNames`.

Comment: Thanks, would you mind explaining why? They're both being called on the same line within the loop?

Comment: I don't know why. I just observed that the only possible case when this code throws an out-of-bounds error is that the `addressCity` array contains less elements than `restaurantNames`. I don't see how the line they are referenced on could possibly be relevant. They are **used** in the same loop, yeah. But does that mean they *have* to have the same number of elements? Nope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the size of your `self.addressCity array`. The size of the array could be less than `self.restaurantNames array`. once i variable will cross the limit of addressCity array. it'll throw this exception

Comment: Well - that doesn't matter if they are calling in the same line or not. You gotta check the list of elements containing by $0.objectForKey("City") first.
Print the length of both the array and items containing by array

Comment: Thanks, I checked and they are both the same size. It might be an issue that the loop seems to be called more than once.

Comment: Use nesting of loops..
for (var i = 0; i < self.restaurantNames.count; i++) 
{
   if(i<=self.addressCity.count)
   {
          self.names += [Name(name: self.restaurantNames[i],    city:self.addressCity[i])]
   }
   else
   {
      self.names += [Name(name: self.restaurantNames[i], city: String.Empty]
   }
}

try this block of code

Comment: Thanks I gave it a shot with this working version: `for (var i = 0; i < self.restaurantNames.count; i++) { if(i<=self.addressCity.count) { self.names += [Name(name: self.restaurantNames[i], city:self.addressCity[i])] } else { self.names += [Name(name: self.restaurantNames[i], city: "")] } }` still the same error. I think it is because the loop is running more than once. How can I clear the struct before the loop is called?

Comment: Well to reset the struct is not recommended. If, still you wanna try this :https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/340786b7-730f-4f06-980f-84194c6e9533/how-do-you-clear-a-struct-empty-a-struct-?forum=csharpgeneral.

Although, you can use some other variable into the loop to check how many times the loop is calling.

Answer (score -2):

If your index range is `0` to `10`
You have `11` elements.  Your loop will try to access the `11` index which is out of bounds.  So try subtracting `1` from `i` if your not accessing your first element at index `0`. Otherwise just subtract `1` from your `array.count`.

Whichever one works will depend whether `i` is increased before you access your array.

So for an array with an index of `0` to `10`,
you're trying to access either `1` to `11`,
or trying to access `0` to `11`.

Subtracting `1` fixes the `1` to `11` problem
(Which is what I suspect is happening).
Subtracting `1` from `array.count` fixes the `0` to `11` problem

Also a simpler way would be with a *for-in-loop*.

Don't have time to post that code will check back when I get off of work